# How to connect to Postgres from the Docker host using docker-compose up -d

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to **connect to the Postgres server inside of a Docker container started via `docker-compose up -d`**, using a Postgres client running on the host (Beekeeper Studio, or TablePlus.)

- I'm running my own Docker image based off of `heroku/heroku:20` (which runs Ubuntu.)
- The Postgres server runs fine.

  - My webapp inside of it runs OK.
  - I can connect with adminer (a web-based SQL client running inside the container.)
  - The ports are configured as `5432:5432` inside of `docker-compose.xml`.
- I can get the IP of the container.

  - Via `docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' heroku20php7container`
- I added `listen_addresses = '*'` to `postgresql.conf`.
- I allowed every host in `pg_hba.conf`.

  - By adding this line: `host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5`.
  - This is probably overkill and I'll want restrict the IP range once I get things working.

Now when I try to connect to Postgres with Beekeeper Studio (or TablePlus) the connection just times out.

What are my options?

Comment: What hostname are you trying to use?

Comment: Are you looking for the solution to restrict access to a few IPs from your database?

Comment: @RobertMoskal When I connect using adminer, I connect to `localhost`. When trying to connect from the host, I tried to use the IP (e.g. 172.26.0.2). Not certain if this answers your question.

Comment: @SumeetKumarYadav No, I just want to be able to connect with an SQL client from the host (macOS) into the Postgres server inside the container. (it's all local development.)

Comment: You said your ports are exposed correctly. Have you tried connecting to `localhost:5432` ?

Comment: From a MacOS host, using Docker Desktop, your _only_ choice is `localhost:5432` as @ErvinSzilagyi suggests; the `docker inspect` IP address isn't reachable.  (And `localhost` works on every platform, unless Docker is in a VM that's visible to you; I'd never recommend manually looking up the per-container IP address.)

Comment: There is no doubt. If everything is set up correctly, you connect to postgres on **localhost:5432**

Comment: Trying to connect to localhost:5432 I get "Connected terminated unexpectedly". I'm a bit at a loss as to where to look or which logs to check.